# Is unitarity equivalent to imposing Ward identity in $U(1)$ gauge theory?

Tags: gauge-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, group-theory, unitarity, ward-identity

I proved in a gauge theory lecture that unitarity violation implies ward identity violation in the simple $U(1)$ case.

I was wondering if this statement can be reversed, i.e can we say that unitarity and Ward identity are equivalent?

**Proof:** In the Gupta-Bleuler quantization for the photon we separate the Hilbert space into physical states and the 'rest', containing the forward photon.

If we assume unitarity on the full theory, i.e on the full Hilbert space, it is not trivial that unitarity will hold if we only consider physical states.
We would like to prove \begin{equation} \delta_{\alpha \beta}=\sum_{\gamma \in Physical} <\alpha|S^\dagger|\gamma><\gamma|S|\beta> \tag{1}\end{equation}

But so far we only know that $$ \delta_{\alpha \beta}=\sum_{\gamma \in All states} <\alpha|S^\dagger|\gamma><\gamma|S|\beta>=-\sum\int<\alpha|S^\dagger|k_1...k_m;\mu_1...\mu_m>\eta^{\mu_1 \mu_1'}...\eta^{\mu_m \mu_m'} <k_1...k_m;\mu_1'...\mu_m'|S|\beta> \tag{2} $$

Then writing $$-\eta^{\mu \nu}=\sum_{T=+,-}\epsilon^\mu_T(k)\epsilon^\nu_T*(k)-\epsilon^\mu_B(k)\epsilon^\nu_F(k)-\epsilon^\mu_F(k)\epsilon^\nu_B(k)$$

where $\epsilon_T$= physical transverse polarization that satisfies $k.\epsilon_T=0$ and $\epsilon_B$,$\epsilon_F$= unphysical polarization (forward and backward). Plugging this formula into (2), we will obtain 'nice' terms that will lead to (1) and terms of the form: $$ <\alpha|S^\dagger|k_1;\mu_1>\epsilon_B^{\mu_1}(k_1)\epsilon_F^{\mu_1'}(k_1)<k_1;\mu_1|S|\beta> \tag{3}$$
which will vanish because of Ward identity.

So Ward identity implies unitarity on physical states.

Could the opposite be true?

Comment: Present the proof you have and we can then attempt to reverse it

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment I just added a sketch of the proof.